# Notices about undefined indexes/variables

Tags: drupal

I am creating my own custom template in Drupal 7, and have some system errors. Can anyone please explain them to me, and how to fix them or direct me to some documentation that will help me solve these issues?
Here are the errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: navigation in include() (line 82 of /Users/Ken/Sites/drupal_cprna/sites/all/themes/na/templates/page.tpl.php).
>       Notice: Undefined variable: secondary_menu_heading in include() (line 107 of /Users/Ken/Sites/drupal_cprna/sites/all/themes/na/templates/page.tpl.php).
>       Notice: Undefined variable: title in include() (line 53 of /Users/Ken/Sites/drupal_cprna/sites/all/themes/na/templates/block.tpl.php).
>       Notice: Undefined variable: title in include() (line 53 of /Users/Ken/Sites/drupal_cprna/sites/all/themes/na/templates/block.tpl.php).
>       Notice: Undefined variable: jump_link_target in include() (line 74 of /Users/Ken/Sites/drupal_cprna/sites/all/themes/na/templates/html.tpl.php).

Answer (score 1):

All of those errors are caused by the respective variables not existing in the various template files.

There's definitely no `$secondary_menu_heading` provided by default in page.tpl.php, and no `jump_link_target` provided by default in `html.tpl.php`.

At a guess I'd say you're basing your theme on another theme that *does* provide those variables to the template files, and you need to do the same. If that's the case have a look at the `template.php` file for that theme, specifically at the `themename_preprocess_x()` functions...that's where the variables are created and provided to the template files.

There's a good overview of how the theming system works on [this post](http://drupal.org/node/173880).

Answer (score 1):

I got same error, using a Zen subtheme in my D7 installation:

> Notice: Undefined variable: title in include() (line 53 of
>   .../sites/all/themes/mysubtheme/templates/block.tpl.php)

This error was causing the titles of my  blocks didn't render at all in the front-end, as I expected.

As Clive said, there was a variable non existing in the page.tpl.php. So, I copied the following function from Zen's template.php to my subtheme template.php file:

```
function mysubtheme_process_block(&$variables, $hook) {
   $variables['title'] = isset($variables['block']->subject) ? $variables['block']->subject : '';
}
```

(However, note that you have to rename the function with "**yoursubtheme**_process_block")

And...voilá, my block's titles shown again. :-)

Many thanks for you comment, Clive. It helped me a lot!

Joan